# How do I change the transparency of Voxels in Ursina Python?

Tags: python, transparency, ursina

I'm currently making Minecraft with Ursina Python, and I'm trying to make a glass material, but I can't figure out how to change a voxel's transparency.

I did not try anything because I don't know the parameter name for changing transparency.

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a minimal reproducible example:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

Set the color to a transparent color. For example:

```
entity.color = color.hsv(0, 0, 1, .5) # 50% transparent white.
```

There's also the shorter way .alpha, if you only want to set the transparency and not the whole color:

```
entity.alpha = .5
```